# How to make Twitter bootstrap modal full screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= image_tag "Background.jpg" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I make a twitter bootstrap modal popup full screen for the above code, I tried playing around with css but was not able get it the way I wanted. Can anyone please help me with it.

Answer (score 328, accepted):

I achieved this in Bootstrap 3 with the following code:

```
.modal-dialog {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.modal-content {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

In general, when you have questions about spacing / padding issues, try right+clicking (or cmd+clicking on mac) the element and select "inspect element" on Chrome or "inspect element with firebug" on Firefox.  Try selecting different HTML elements in the "elements" panel and editing the CSS on the right in real-time until you get the padding / spacing you want.

**[Here is a live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8XdVt/show/)**

[Here is a link to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8XdVt/)

Comment: I'd also add `margin: 0` to `.modal-dialog`.

Comment: BTW: `.modal-content` 's hight break when content overflows at the bottom and scrolling down. It should be `min-height: 100%; height: auto;`

Comment: If designing for a mobile app, you can put Chris' CSS inside a media query to have normal modal width for wider screens @media(max-width: 768px) { ... }

Comment: you can also add .modal { padding: ...px } if you need "almost" full screen modal

Comment: Does this also work for printing? I am struggling to print a modal to a full page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41889627/print-modal-content-as-full-a4-page

Comment: I think only `.modal-dialog {
  width: 100%; }` is okay. It worked for me.

Comment: Might be looking for this

https://noreiller.github.io/bootstrap-modal-carousel/modal-fullscreen.html

Comment: `.modal-dialog` also needs `max-width: 100%;` for **bootstrap 4**

Answer (score 84):

I've came up with a "responsive" solution for fullscreen modals:

Fullscreen Modals that can be enabled only **on certain breakpoints**. In this way **the modal will display "normal" on wider (desktop) screens and fullscreen on smaller (tablet or mobile) screens**, giving it the feeling of a native app.

Implemented for **Bootstrap 3** and **Bootstrap 4**. Included by default in **Bootstrap 5**.

---

### Bootstrap v5

Fullscreen modals are included by default in **Bootstrap 5**: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#fullscreen-modal

---

### Bootstrap v4

The following generic code should work:

```
.modal {
  padding: 0 !important; // override inline padding-right added from js
}
.modal .modal-dialog {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: none;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.modal .modal-content {
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.modal .modal-body {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

By including the scss code below, it generates the following classes that need to be added to the `.modal` element:

```
+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|                     |   xs    |   sm    |   md    |   lg    |   xl    | 
|                     | <576px  | ≥576px  | ≥768px  | ≥992px  | ≥1200px |
+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|.modal-fullscreen    |  100%   | default | default | default | default | 
+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|.modal-fullscreen-sm |  100%   |  100%   | default | default | default | 
+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|.modal-fullscreen-md |  100%   |  100%   |  100%   | default | default |
+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|.modal-fullscreen-lg |  100%   |  100%   |  100%   |  100%   | default |
+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|.modal-fullscreen-xl |  100%   |  100%   |  100%   |  100%   |  100%   |
+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

The scss code is:

```
@mixin modal-fullscreen() {
  padding: 0 !important; // override inline padding-right added from js

  .modal-dialog {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .modal-content {
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
  }

  .modal-body {
    overflow-y: auto;
  }

}

@each $breakpoint in map-keys($grid-breakpoints) {
  @include media-breakpoint-down($breakpoint) {
    $infix: breakpoint-infix($breakpoint, $grid-breakpoints);

    .modal-fullscreen#{$infix} {
      @include modal-fullscreen();
    }
  }
}
```

Demo on Codepen: https://codepen.io/andreivictor/full/MWYNPBV/

---

### Bootstrap v3

Based on previous responses to this topic (@Chris J, @kkarli), the following generic code should work:

```
.modal {
  padding: 0 !important; // override inline padding-right added from js
}

.modal .modal-dialog {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.modal .modal-content {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

If you want to use responsive fullscreen modals, use the following classes that need to be added to `.modal` element:

- `.modal-fullscreen-md-down` - the modal is fullscreen for screens smaller than `1200px`.
- `.modal-fullscreen-sm-down` - the modal is fullscreen for screens smaller than `922px`.
- `.modal-fullscreen-xs-down` - the modal is fullscreen for screen smaller than `768px`.

Take a look at the following code:

```
/* Extra small devices (less than 768px) */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .modal-fullscreen-xs-down {
    padding: 0 !important;
  }
  .modal-fullscreen-xs-down .modal-dialog {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .modal-fullscreen-xs-down .modal-content {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
  } 
}

/* Small devices (less than 992px) */
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .modal-fullscreen-sm-down {
    padding: 0 !important;
  }
  .modal-fullscreen-sm-down .modal-dialog {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .modal-fullscreen-sm-down .modal-content {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}

/* Medium devices (less than 1200px) */
@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .modal-fullscreen-md-down {
    padding: 0 !important;
  }
  .modal-fullscreen-md-down .modal-dialog {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .modal-fullscreen-md-down .modal-content {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}
```

Demo is available on Codepen: https://codepen.io/andreivictor/full/KXNdoO.

Those who use Sass as a preprocessor can take advantage of the following mixin:

```
@mixin modal-fullscreen() {
  padding: 0 !important; // override inline padding-right added from js

  .modal-dialog {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .modal-content {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
  }

}
```

Comment: In Bootstrap 4, if you're using `.modal-dialog-scrollable` on the element with `.modal-dialog`, you may want to add the following to the above v4 SCSS code to force the modal to extend the full height of the viewport:
`.modal-dialog.modal-dialog-scrollable { max-height: 100%; }` and `.modal-dialog.modal-dialog-scrollable .modal-content { max-height: 100%; }`

Answer (score 28):

The chosen solution does not preserve the round corner style.
To preserve the round corners, you should reduce the width and height a little bit and remove the border radius 0. Also it doesn't show the vertical scroll bar...

```
.modal-dialog {
  width: 98%;
  height: 92%;
  padding: 0;
}

.modal-content {
  height: 99%;
}
```

Comment: a more correct answer that retains the feel of model with rounded corners, the accepted answer presents an overlay layer instead of modal

Comment: If the modal is occupying the full screen, it would look horrible (IMHO) if you have round corners around it.

Answer (score 19):

For bootstrap 4 I have to add media query with max-width: none

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .modal-dialog { max-width: none; }
}

.modal-dialog {
  width: 98%;
  height: 92%;
  padding: 0;
}

.modal-content {
  height: 99%;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

for bootstrap 4

add classes :

```
.full_modal-dialog {
  width: 98% !important;
  height: 92% !important;
  min-width: 98% !important;
  min-height: 92% !important;
  max-width: 98% !important;
  max-height: 92% !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.full_modal-content {
  height: 99% !important;
  min-height: 99% !important;
  max-height: 99% !important;
}
```

and in HTML :

```
<div role="document" class="modal-dialog full_modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content full_modal-content">
```

Answer (score 12):

The following class will make a full-screen modal in Bootstrap:

```
.full-screen {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

I'm not sure how the inner content of your modal is structured, this may have an effect on the  overall height depending on the CSS that is associated with it.

Comment: what is .fullscreen ? I included the css in #myModal it worked for the width but not the height.

Comment: `.fullscreen` is a class I created to solve the issue, it is not included in Bootstrap. Can you post a sample of your code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [CodePen](http://codepen.io/)? I can't help you without seeing your code.

Comment: for add height you need to add height on model-body not on #myModal.

Answer (score 7):

The [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18522320/4022154) from @Chris J had some issues with margins and overflow.
The proposed changes by @YanickRochon and @Joana, based on the fiddel from @Chris J can be found in the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8XdVt/405/).

That's the CSS code that worked for me:

```
.modal-dialog {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.modal-content {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For bootstap 4.5:
I just copied this code from bootstap 5.scss to my sass and its amazing:

```
@media (max-width: 1399.98px) 
  .modal-fullscreen-xxl-down 
    width: 100vw
    max-width: none
    height: 100%
    margin: 0
  
  .modal-fullscreen-xxl-down .modal-content 
    height: 100%
    border: 0
    border-radius: 0
  
  .modal-fullscreen-xxl-down .modal-header 
    border-radius: 0
  
  .modal-fullscreen-xxl-down .modal-body 
    overflow-y: auto
  
  .modal-fullscreen-xxl-down .modal-footer 
    border-radius: 0
```

For html:

```
<!-- Full screen modal -->
<div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen-xxl-down">
  ...
</div>
```

Its all about controling margin, width and height of the right div.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your DIV tags as below.

Find the more details > http://thedeveloperblog.com/bootstrap-modal-with-full-size-and-scrolling

```
</style>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
   More Details
</button>
</br>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="container">;
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal Title</h3>
          </div>
              <div class="modal-body" >
                Your modal text 
              </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>                                      
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.modal {
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
        .modal .modal-dialog {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: none;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .modal .modal-content {
            height: 100%;
            border: 0;
            border-radius: 0;
        }
        .modal .modal-body {
            overflow-y: auto;
        }
```

**This is way perfect working in my case Thanks alot**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to have the Modal Bigger than the normal Then No need of writing the .css code, we can directly write the class of bootstrap modal **

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="mappingModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
```

Only **modal-dialog modal-xl** and done.

Answer (score -1):

My variation of the solution:
(scss)

```
  .modal {
        .modal-dialog.modal-fs {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            box-shadow: none;
            height: 100%;
            .modal-content {
                border: none;
                border-radius: 0;
                box-shadow: none;
                box-shadow: none;
                height: 100%;
            }
        }
    }
```

(css)

```
.modal .modal-dialog.modal-fs {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  height: 100%;
}
.modal .modal-dialog.modal-fs .modal-content {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.modal.in .modal-dialog {
 width:100% !important; 
 min-height: 100%;
 margin: 0 0 0 0 !important;
 bottom: 0px !important;
 top: 0px;
}


.modal-content {
    border:0px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2) !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.5) !important;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0,0,0,.5) !important;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.modal-dialog {
 position: fixed !important;
 margin:0px !important;
}

.bootstrap-dialog .modal-header {
    border-top-left-radius: 0px !important; 
    border-top-right-radius: 0px !important;
}


@media (min-width: 768px)
.modal-dialog {
    width: 100% !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Try to explain more clearly why this is an answer to the question.

Answer (score -1):

Use This:

```
.modal-full {
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.modal-full .modal-content {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

and so:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-full">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content ">
            <div class="modal-header ">                    
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; 
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">hi</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```