# min-height not working for bootstrap modal window

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-window

I tried to create a modal window having full height even if the content is small. I set css min-height:100% to .modal-dialog and tried various other options. But min-height is not working for modal window.

My requirement is:

Even if content is small modal window should be full screen

If content is huge modal window should have a scroll bar and should include all content.

Comment: apply both `height:100%` and `min-height:100%`

Comment: I tried that also but not worked

Comment: try using `min-height: 100vh;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use height 100% only if the object is inside an element with known height. If the parent have no height, the browser has nothing to reference.

Solution in pure CSS:

```
.my-div {
position:fixed !important;
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
}
```

You can set in jquery function where you open the dialog:

```
$('.my-div').css('height', window.innerHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.modal-dialog {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.modal-content {
  min-height: 100%;
  height:auto;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

[How to make Twitter bootstrap modal full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432394/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-modal-full-screen)