# Modal covering the entire screen of the device

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I am trying to design a modal that covers the full width of the device. Here is my attempt:

```
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="container-fluid modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" style=" max-width: 100vw;" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Preview</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="padding:50px;"  id="result">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--MODAL-->
```

This is what I am getting : 
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHJVb.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Twitter bootstrap modal full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432394/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-modal-full-screen)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Creating a full screen modal is different in the latest **Bootstrap 4**, than in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432394/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-modal-full-screen) for Bootstrap 3.

```
.modal-full {
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.modal-full .modal-content {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Then add `modal-full` class to the modal:

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-full" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Demo**: [Bootstrap 4 Full Screen Modal](https://www.codeply.com/go/rNFv5RJJqn/bootstrap-4-modal-full-screen)