# Simplest way to create a modal window for a single image that resizes with screen size?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.7 and want to know how to implement a modal window for a single image. I am trying to use inline styling only to simplify the process.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to [How to make Twitter bootstrap modal full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432394/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-modal-full-screen), you can do this :

```css
.modal-dialog {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.modal-content {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-body">
    Image here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Am I supposed to insert my image like <img src="image.jpg" alt="image"> or some other way? I do the aforementioned but my image does not show up at all on my web page. And yes, the image is in my directory.